# Challenges with headless turtlebot_gazebo on remote machine

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, turtlebot-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Before trying this I did update my ubuntu/ROS machine.
Using ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.12 and trying to run simulated turtlebot headless (i.e. with no OGRE rendering via the -r argument).

> [..../simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/sensors/Sensor.cc:175]
> left_cliff_sensor sensor has no controller.

Duplicated for leftfront_cliff_sensor, right_cliff_sensor, rightfront_cliff_sensor, and wall_sensor.

How do I fix this? Is this some how related to the lack of OGRE rendering somehow?

Also, occasionally I observe the following message (repeatedly) when I run the roslaunch command (I make no changes between tries).

> [ERROR] [1331395233.928128897, 0.915000000]: TF_NAN_INPUT: Ignoring transform for child_frame_id "/wheelodom" from authority "default_authority" because of a nan value in the transform (nan nan nan) (0.000000 0.000000 0.764947 0.644094)

What should I do to track that down?

Finally, sometimes the /odom isn't what I'd expect it to be as well.

```
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 6.97715623635e+22
      y: 1.83193543179e+25
```

and other times it is:

```
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: -1.70336659266e-06
      y: -7.78686316816e-12
```

In this latter case the system responds to twist commands as would be expected.

I assume that the simulation has "exploded" in the former case as the robot doesn't move when twist commands are issued (at least according to /odom).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29482/challenges-with-headless-turtlebot_gazebo-on-remote-machine/) by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2022 on 2012-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. I hope this information helps you.

The problem you see may be the same problem that I found last week.

I found "using variables without initialize" bug in "simulator_gazebo_plugins".
That cause the very large value of odometry {x, y}.

[problem]
When you try to use turtlebot simulator (gazebo),
sometimes the node "/gazebo" publishes the topic "/odom" with very large
initial position {x, y} like 1e+31 or so.

[cause]
In turtlebot_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_create.cpp,
variables below are used without being initialized.

- prev_update_time
- odom_pose[0]
- odom_pose[1]
- odom_pose[2]

I know that recentry turtlebot_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_create.cpp was patched
about NaN value (in GazeboRosCreate::UpdateChild()) .
The patch didn't fix the problem I found.

I don't know how to report bug-report and patch, so I'm glad if someone does.

[environment]

- ubuntu 11.10 32bit
- ros-electric (updated with apt-get)

[how to reproduce]
(not 100%. because that is caused with "using uninitialized variable" in C++.)

Start 3 terminals separately and type it.

```
$ roscore
$ roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_empty_world.launch
$ rostopic echo /odom
```

Check values of pose.pose.position.x and y.
If it shows like below, you successed to reproduce.

```
pose:
  pose:
    position:
      x: 1.86493744726e+31
      y: 4.86171422416e+30
```

[how to fix]
initialize variables.

[patch]
keizo@soi:~/ros_workspace/turtlebot_gazebo_plugins.keizo/src$ diff -c /opt/ros/electric/stacks /turtlebot_simulator/turtlebot_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_create.cpp .

```
*** /opt/ros/electric/stacks/turtlebot_simulator/turtlebot_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_create.cpp 2012-02-29 07:52:33.000000000 +0900
--- ./gazebo_ros_create.cpp 2012-03-11 22:59:59.026536682 +0900
***************
*** 153,158 ****
--- 153,159 ----
    js_.velocity.push_back(0);
    js_.effort.push_back(0);

+   prev_update_time_ = 0;
    last_cmd_vel_time_ = 0;
  }

***************
*** 172,177 ****
--- 173,184 ----
    if (joints_[FRONT]) set_joints_[FRONT] = true;
    if (joints_[REAR]) set_joints_[REAR] = true;

+   //initialize time and odometry position
+   prev_update_time_ = last_cmd_vel_time_ =
+     Simulator::Instance()->GetSimTime();
+   odom_pose_[0] = 0.0;
+   odom_pose_[1] = 0.0;
+   odom_pose_[2] = 0.0;
  }

  void GazeboRosCreate::FiniChild()
```

---

[[[ Unnecessary additional information ]]]
[indirect problem]
When you try to use turtlebot simulator (gazebo) and slam_gmapping,
the node slam_gmapping downs with a message "bad_alloc" exception.

[cause]
Ordinary,  the initial value of odometory's {x, y} should be nearly equal to zero.
but it shows sometimes very large like 1e+31 or so.

When the node "slam_gmapping" receives that large value, it try to enlarge map too much.
And it cause a "not enough memory" situation and "bad_alloc" exception.

If you want to reproduce, you need to add "output_frame" param described blelow
to turtlebot_gazebo/launch/robot.launch .

```
 <node pkg="robot_pose_ekf parameter" .... >
    ....
    <param name="output_frame" value="odom"/>
 </node>
```

[comment]
I'm not good at English, I apologize about my poor English.
I hope this information helps you. and also me.

---

Originally posted by [keizo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1950/keizo/) with karma: 26 on 2012-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1